# Updating DataTable column from another DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset, updates

Using .NET 4 C#, I have a DataSet containing two DataTables generated from imported csv files, created from form registration data. One contains a record ID and a timestamp. The other is a list of product registrations (name, address, etc.), with the corresponding record ID (about 10,000 records)

How can I insert the timestamp from the first datatable into the second datatable matching the correct record ID? Can I attach a DataAdapter to existing DataSet and query against them that way? I was hoping I could add a timestamp column to me second datatable and update that from the first.

I know this doesn't make sense (why not include the timestamp when exporting the form data?). I'm using a Joomla form module for registrations, and the export does not include the timestamp. From the DB, I can export the timestamp and record ID data that matches, but the DataBase structure splits the record fields into separate tables, and I can't figure out how to merge the entire record back together into usable content, so I'm stuck with two csv's displaying data for the same record).

Any nudge in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course just iterate all records yourself and match them up.  But you can also set up a relationship between the DataTables in the dataset, then create a computed column in the records datatable that pulls a parent column's value.  See this example: http://windowsdevcenter.com/dotnet/2003/05/26/datacolumn_expressions.html

See this article on how to actually add relationships: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Toward the bottom:

> Parent.ColumnName     Column in a parent table

So after you create the relationship, you'd do something like: `ds["Table2"].Columns.Add("Timestamp", typeof(DateTime), "Parent.Timestamp")`

Comment: Thank you! Have lots more this type work coming so appreciate the education very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

add new column to 2nd datatable

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("DateCol", typeof(System.DateTime));
dt2.Columns.Add(dc);
```

Now update this datecol column in 2nd datatable using first datatable

```
dt2.AsEnumerable().Join(  dt1.AsEnumerable(),
       dt2Rows => dt2Rows.ItemArray["record_id"],
       dt1Rows => dt1Rows.ItemArray["record_id"],
       (dt2Rows, dt1Rows) => new { dt2Rows, dt1Rows })
 .ToList()
 .ForEach(i => i.dt2Rows.SetField("DateCol", i.dt1Rows.ItemArray["DateCol"]));
```

To use above linq query you have to Import the [Systems.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) namespace in your class file

Comment: DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("DateCol", typeof(System.DateTime));
Registrations.Columns.Add(dc);

      Registrations.AsEnumerable().Join(TimeStamps.AsEnumerable(),
               dt2Rows => dt2Rows.ItemArray[Convert.ToInt32("ID")],               
               dt1Rows => dt1Rows.ItemArray[Convert.ToInt32("ID")],
               (dt2Rows, dt1Rows) => new { dt2Rows, dt1Rows })
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(i => t.dt2Rows.SetField("DateCol", i.dt1Rows.ItemArray[Convert.ToInt32("DateCol")]));

Comment: Sorry, still figuring this system out :(  I had to cast a couple things as int, but seems ready to build, except for "t does not exist in current context).

Comment: @user1366794, updated answer, there was typo i was using t instead of i in ForEach